# How to prove that a function similar to Thomae is integrable (using Advanced calculus only )

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, analysis

$$ f(x) = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
1 & { x= 1/n}, n \in \mathbb{N}, \\
0  &\text{otherwise}
\end{array} \right. $$

Prove that $f$ is integrable [Darboux] on [0,1].

I believe that the proof will be similar to this but not exactly, so could anyone tell me the differences please?

> [image]
>   [image]

Comment: Is your "Darboux" sum deals only with partitions with equal length of subintervals?

Comment: No it does not @xbh

Comment: This one is easier. Only one interval contains infinitely many points.

Comment: How to choose the partition here? @xbh

Comment: what is the idea of the partition been choosen in the example?

Comment: To be clear, for each $\varepsilon >0$, we only need to find **one** partition s.t. $U(f,P)-L(f,P)< \varepsilon $, correct? [Various text may use different theorems]

Comment: This is a special case of a more general result: *if $f$ is bounded on $[a, b] $ and the set $D$ of discontinuities of $f$ has a finite number of limit points then $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[a, b] $*. The general result can be proved using an argument similar to the one given in answer by @xbh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each $\varepsilon >0$, there is some $N\in \mathbb N^* \colon N < 2/\varepsilon$. Let $1/(N+1) \leqslant x_1 < 1/N$, then $[x_1, 1]$ contains $S = \{1/N, 1/(N-1), \dots, 1/2, 1\}$. Now use closed intervals with length $\leqslant 1/N^2$ to cover each single point $1/j$ foe $j =1, \dots, N$, and add other points if you like, then
$$
U(f,P) \leqslant 1 (x_1 - 0) +  1 \cdot \frac 1{N^2} \cdot N + 0\cdot \sum_{S \cap [x_{j-1},x_j] =\varnothing} (x_j - x_{j-1})\leqslant \frac 1{N+1} + \frac 1N < \frac 2N < \varepsilon,
$$
where $P=\{0, x_1, \cdots, 1\}$ that contains the endpoints of the aforementioned intervals. Clearly $L(f,P) =0$, since every interval contains points not in $S$, so $U(f,P) - L(f,P) < \varepsilon$.

#### Remark

We first notice that $\{1/n\}_1^\infty$ converges to $0$, so we could choose $x_1$ s.t. $[0,x_1]$ covers infinitely many points of them. For the rest of them, each are "isolated", so we could use intervals with length as small as possible to cover them. Thus the upper sum w.r.t. such partition would be small enough as well.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3019732/let-f-be-a-bounded-function-on-0-1-and-integrable-on-delta-1-for-every   Can you look at this question for me please?

Comment: this is the partition of the new problem not an explanation for the example correct?

Comment: @hopefully Yes.

Comment: what do you mean by the statement "the rest of them are isolated"?

Comment: $x_{1}$ is so strange for me, what values it can take?

Comment: why the closed intervals have length < or equal 1/(N^2)?

Comment: $x_1$ is the first point of the partition. The end points of the intervals also belong to the partition. I just pick partition points $x_j, x_{j+1}$ s.t. $1/m \in [x_j, x_{j+1}] \cap [0,1]$ and $x_{j+1} - x_j \leqslant 1/N^2$ for each $m = 1,2, \dots, N$ where $j$ is some index.

Comment: why the length of the interval you picked is less than $1/(N^2)$?

Comment: what are the other points that I will add?

Comment: I want to make $U(f,P)$ as small as possible, and according to my inequalities, $1/N^2$ would work. We don't have requirements for other partition points. Any points would work.